# Uni code error while installing moodle

Tags: php, moodle

This is my first time that I am installing moodle. on server checks page, it is saying me to install uni code with this message

**It is required that you store all your data in Unicode format (UTF-8). New installations must be performed into databases that have their default character set as Unicode. If you are upgrading, you should perform the UTF-8 migration process (see the Admin page).**

I am using xampp. How i can install unicode?

Answer (score -1):

You are better off just downloading the XAMP version that is setup for Moodle already: http://download.moodle.org/windows/

But if you want to use your existing XAMP, the problem is because your database collation should be "utf8_unicode_ci": http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Windows_installation_using_XAMPP#Create_the_MySQL_database

Comment: I solved it by changing the charset of the moodle table to utf-8